# rewrite jquery so that it targets only parent ul li

Tags: jquery

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X4uvD/

I'm trying to make this jquery code rewrite only parent ul li and not ul li inside.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
//This is for footer slider, it rewrites 1 ul into several uls that contain 4 li max.
    // get the container, useful for later too...
    var container = $(".fproductslides");

    // get all available UL and LI elements...
    // this doesn't order featured listings at the top of the list
    // var li_elements = container.find("LI").clone();
    // this does order featured listings at the top of the list
    var li_elements = container.find("LI.slidefeatured").clone();
    li_elements = li_elements.add(container.find('LI:not(.slidefeatured)').clone());

    // remove the current content so that we can rebuild it for the slider...
    container.find("UL").remove();

    // build the slider container...
    var slide_container = $("<div />");
    slide_container.addClass("slides_container");

    // tricky part: looping through the LI's and building each of the slides...
    // first create some helpful variables...
    var li_elements_per_slide = 3;
    var li_counter = 0;
    // create the first slide, with a UL to hold the LI's...
    var current_li_div = $("<div />");
    current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));

    // loop through the LI's...
    li_elements.each(function(index, element){

        li_counter++;
        var current_li = $(element).clone();
        current_li_div.find("UL").append(current_li);

        if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide == 0)
        {
            // we've hit 4 in this list, so add the slide and make
            // a new one, using same code as before...
            container.append(current_li_div);
            current_li_div = $("<div />");
            current_li_div.append($("<ul />"));
        }

    });

    // we might have an uneven number of LI's, so we need to check for this...
    if (li_counter % li_elements_per_slide != 0)
        container.append(current_li_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent()` method to get parent DOM elements. also you can pass a selector string like `ul.parent` to filter parent element.

```
<ul class='parent'>
    <li class='child'></li>
</ul>
```

`$('li.child').parent('ul.parent')`

Comment: How would that translate into my specific example? I know what I've to do but script I've is a bit complicated for me to understand... Can you please help?